# For each ID in a group keep only the first value !=0 within the group, set other to 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a df with product ID, for each product I have some information, I need to keep only the first information !=0 within the group, all the others need to be set to zero. I am working with pandas.

This is the input:

| ID | Info |
| --- | --- |
| AA | 0 |
| AA | 20 |
| AA | 30 |
| BB | 10 |
| BB | 0 |
| BB | 20 |

This is the output i would like:

| ID | Info |
| --- | --- |
| AA | 0 |
| AA | 20 |
| AA | **0** |
| BB | 10 |
| BB | 0 |
| BB | **0** |

thank you for your help

Answer (score 4):

We can compare the `Info` column with `0` to create a boolean mask, then check for the `duplicated` values in this mask per unique `ID` and update the values in column `Info` with `0` corresponding to duplicated values

```
df.loc[df.assign(m=df['Info'].ne(0)).duplicated(['ID', 'm']), 'Info'] = 0
```

---

```
   ID  Info
0  AA     0
1  AA    20
2  AA     0
3  BB    10
4  BB     0
5  BB     0
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the condition the use `groupby` + `idxmax` to find the row where it first occurs for each group. Use `where` to turn everything but those rows to 0 and fill the rest with 0.

Because the condition check uses the same value as the fill value, it doesn't matter that we mask all of the 0s with the `where` (or that idxmax will pick the first index even for groups with all 0s).

For this to work properly you must have a non-duplicated Index.

```
ids = df['Info'].ne(0).groupby(df['ID']).idxmax()
df['Info'] = df['Info'].where(df.index.isin(ids)).fillna(0, downcast='infer')

   ID  Info
0  AA     0
1  AA    20
2  AA     0
3  BB    10
4  BB     0
5  BB     0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try a `idxmax` after filtering for !=0 on the info column, then mask using `where`

```
s = df.loc[df['Info'].ne(0).groupby(df['ID']).transform('idxmax'),'Info']
s.index = df.index
df['New_Info'] = s.where(df['Info'].eq(s),0)
```

---

```
print(df)

   ID  Info  New_Info
0  AA     0         0
1  AA    20        20
2  AA    30         0
3  BB    10        10
4  BB     0         0
5  BB    20         0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df["Info"] = df.groupby("ID")["Info"].transform(
    lambda x: x * (x.index == x.gt(0).idxmax())
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   ID  Info
0  AA     0
1  AA    20
2  AA     0
3  BB    10
4  BB     0
5  BB     0
```